# Usage of "develop [a system] for + -ing" AND "integrate [something] into the system"

Tags: grammaticality

Does the following sound correct?

> I have developed a system for collecting, storing, and processing large volumes of stock market data. I have also implemented an algorithm that predicts the price of a stock from historical data and integrated it into the system.

Is there a better way to write these sentences? I am worried about the use of the following structures:

- develop [a system] for + -ing
- integrate [(the implementation of) the algorithm] into the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence sounds just fine.

The second sentence could change a bit, I think. "Implement" means to put something into effect. So if you "implemented an algorithm", that means you have already "integrated it into the system". So you can just remove the last part of that sentence.

But if you want to separate the two thoughts, you could say that you've "developed an algorithm ... and integrated it into the system".